# How can I test push/C2DM notifications to Android Application?

Tags: php, android, simulator, android-c2dm

I need to implement push/C2DM notifications on my website, I installed the Android 3.0 platform sdk, simulator, and I installed the application from an .apk file.

Now, I'm using a ZF powered sites and I want to test my notification, is it possible through the simulator?

I didn't write the actual Android Application, and I'm not able to do anything on it, but what should I know to use it with PHP?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with ZF powered sites?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push C2DM messages to third-party applications - not without their active participation. Google's technical implementation explicitly forbids that.

An app specifies a Google account it wishes to receive notifications from; in order to send notifications, you need to log on with a Google account. For everything to work, the account has to be the same. So unless you know what account does the app wants messages from, *and* you know the password to that account, no C2DM for you.